# How to chop photo in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating one app for image editing, I want to apply Instant Alpha tools for image selection and cut.

I dont know how to do instant alpha effect on image.
Any Library for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by crop image?

Comment: I want to apply Instant Alpha crop tools for my iPhone app.

Comment: Try this: [PEPhotoCropEditor](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor)